# Spring cors headers missing interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-security, cors

I am trying to add cors headers to every request in spring. But when I return `false` in an interceptor(`preHandle()`) there are no cors headers.
This is how I add the headers:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${cors.url}")
    private String corsUrl;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        // My interceptors.
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(this.corsUrl)
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

I use interceptors to check if the JWT token in a request is valid.
The cors headers are working fine when the interceptors are not used, but I really need them.

I think the headers are added after the interceptors, so when I return false(in `preHandle()`) the headers are just not added.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I have a temporary fix by putting the cors headers in an interceptor that is executed first, it works but doesn't look as nice as the config file.